# Media Queries and CSS Performance

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I want to start nesting my media queries in SCSS rules like Chris Coiyer explains here: http://css-tricks.com/naming-media-queries/

E.g.

```
#breadcrumbs {
    display: none;
    @include font-size(13);
    margin: 8px 0 0;
    @include at-least(768) {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

This seems like a much better way to organise my SCSS, but it will result in *way* more media queries than if I continue to put them all in one place.

I assume it will impact the performance of the CSS a bit, but I guess I'm really looking for people's opinions. Is the performance hit substantial, and is it worth doing it this way for the ease of organisation it provides?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at less?

It's a very clean way to write sudo css. It compiles into css. I think it might give you the readability you are looking for without sacrificing the performance.

More info:

http://lesscss.org/

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I'm already using SCSS as I explained. The question is how much media queries affect performance.

Comment: @OP you stated in your question you were looking for opinions, this is Seths opinion, so yes he kinda is answering your question...

Comment: @lukeocom: Just FYI, at-OP does not actually ping anybody unless their username is OP.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is performance, why not create a some page / CSS variations and actually measure real world results? This way you have true metrics plus are looking at the page as a whole, so you can keep things in perspective.

My favourie testing site is http://www.webpagetest.org and there are lots of others.